# Prevent eth0 from adding default route

Tags: debian, routing, ethernet

I am looking for a way to prevent eth0 interface from adding a default route to my main routing table on my Linux machine. I have a Debian distribution (Jessie - 8.0) and was looking at the post-up directive in `/etc/network/interfaces`. My current configuration looks as follows:

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:4b:f4:9e  
          inet addr:172.16.2.82  Bcast:172.16.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe4b:f49e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:187402 (183.0 KiB)  TX bytes:22251 (21.7 KiB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.178.142.185  P-t-P:192.200.1.21  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:2918 (2.8 KiB)  TX bytes:3426 (3.3 KiB)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up /sbin/route del default dev eth0
```

**ip route show table main**

```
default dev ppp0  scope link 
default via 172.16.0.40 dev eth0  metric 202 
10.64.64.65 dev ppp1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.181.104.9 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.23.201  metric 303 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.62.145  metric 305 
172.16.0.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.2.160  metric 202 
192.168.42.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.1 
192.200.1.21 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.179.96.79
```

Sadly, this approach only works if the interface is brought up using ifup eth0, and not when the cable is physically connected and ip assigned. Even still, this approach doesn't delete the default entry and ifup gives the following error:

```
    Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
    Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
    All rights reserved.
    For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

    Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:4b:f4:9e
    Sending on   LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:4b:f4:9e
    Sending on   Socket/fallback
    DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
    DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
    DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
    DHCPOFFER from 172.16.0.8
    DHCPACK from 172.16.0.8
    eminstBootdpxeboot.com option - discarded
    eminstBootdpxeboot.com option - discarded
    bound to 172.16.2.82 -- renewal in 12663 seconds.
    SIOCDELRT: No such process
    Failed to bring up eth0.
```

I would like to know a proper way to ensure that the default route is not added through eth0 and **not** have to bring up eth0 manually using `ifup` (to leverage post-up) but rather use the one that is already initialized on boot.

Comment: I am using Jessie 8.0

Comment: Is this an answer for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298995/default-gateway-route-being-automatically-added-to-main-table

Comment: Your interface and it's routes are controlled by DHCP. Your DHCP server is the first place you should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and remove `routers` from the `request` statement so that your DHCP client does not request default route configuration along with its address request.

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail. Still the default route comes back up in the main routing table.